# Get index of row

Tags: c#, dataset, indexing

I am working with a windows application.

I load a dataset with dataadapter.Then I link this dataset to my controls(textboxes) in my form.
Now I want to khow that what row is display at each time.
Thanks.

Comment: i link this dataset to my controls(textboxes) in my form , how you do this?

Comment: Be more specific about your design if you want a proper answer. We are not in your brain

Answer (score 0):

i think , you should refer to this artical

[Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301575.aspx)

or Try below code

```
 BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(new your data set ,"");
  bs.Current will give you the current item in the your set.
```